# deadlocks in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how missing indexes on tables can cause deadlocks in SQL Server?

I referred [this](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/11/24/deadlocks-caused-by-missing-indexes-in-sql-server/) 
but could not understand the logic which author wants to convey. can someone explain in more detail?
and also how creating indexes prevent deadlock.

moreover what difference does clustered and no-clustered indexes play a role here?

Comment: This may help: http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/inside-sql-server-indexing-and-locking

Comment: This topic is WAY more than an online forum. Seems that doing some massive amounts of research on indexes is needed. Here is an excellent series of article covering nearly every aspect of indexes in sql server. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/